# How to check if a property contains a property

Tags: javascript, properties, conditional-statements

I need to check if a property contains a property, right now I am using if statements like in the example

Heres an example object

```
var Foo = {
    "bar" : 
        {
            "foobar":
                {
                    "barfoo":1
                }
        }
}
```

And I need to check if `barfoo` exists, but first I need to check if all the other properties are there, because they might not be depending if another function has been run or not. I can't really lessen the levels of this structure either so that isn't an option.

Currently I am doing something similar to this:

```
var d = Foo;
if (d) {
    d = d.bar;
    if (d) {
        d = d.foobar;
        if (d) {
            d = d.barfoo;
            if(d){
                console.log(d);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"I can't really lessen the levels of this structure either so that isn't an option"_? If you absolutely require nested conditionals then you're doing alright.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More robust solution: check in any depth of the object

```
var Foo = {
    "bar": {
        "foobar": {
            "barfoo": {
                "ddd": 1
            }
        }
    }
};

function checkProps(obj) {
    var ref = obj, arg, i;
    for (i = 1; i < arguments.length; i += 1) {
        arg = arguments[i];
        if(ref.hasOwnProperty(arg)){
            ref = ref[arg]
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
//the function takes the object to search as first parameter and any other properties [,prop1,prop2,...]
console.log(checkProps(Foo, 'bar', 'foobar', 'barfoo', 'ddd'));
```

Comment: +1 I was going to suggest something similar, but passing a string with the target path, like "bar.foobar.barfoo.ddd", then split it and loop. Also, a variation of that could return the value of the target property, or undefined if not found (undefined because that's what you get when you try to read a non-existing property on a single level).

Comment: What happens if `ref === 0`? That would mean that it would return false

Comment: Would  `&& ref !== 0` fix that?

Comment: Its one of those gotcha things eh.

Comment: Yes - if conditions on false values in js are a bitch somethimes ^^

Comment: Nice solution. I'd make a slight change though.
Object.prototype.checkProps = function(){}, and change obj to this.

Then you can just do: Foo.checkProps('bar','foobar','barfoo','ddd');

Comment: Why not set ref to obj in the first place instead of defining a null value? Also you can just use `var ref, arg;` in the top of the arguments and they will be default undefined;

Comment: The application is so large (4000 - 5000) lines that I don't really want to give every single object an un-needed function because I use object a heck of a lot.

Comment: Fair enough. But its on the prototype which is shared between objects, its in one place. The function isn't created each time you create an object.

Comment: @laurencek - it's a good suggestion although it's always best not to override the default javascript/pollute golbal scope.

Comment: @SmartLemon - I write it like this so it will be more easy to read - of course you can enhance it in any way you want but to define multiple vars in one "var" and play with the reference - it does not change either way and it harder to understand what i did

Comment: @SmartLemon That check for `!== 0` is not enough, it will still return false for null, undefined, and false itself. [Checking for own properties](http://jsfiddle.net/WktwR/) would be safer (but obviously won't work if you're checking for inherited properties).

Answer (score 5):

You could do it all in one `if` statement:

```
if (d && d.bar && d.bar.foobar && d.bar.foobar.barfoo)
```

This works because the javascript stops checking the if statement if any of the elements fail, so it doesn't error with something like `cannot check property of undefined`.

Otherwise you could use a try catch statement:

```
var barfoo;
try{
  barfoo = d.bar.foobar.barfoo
}
catch(e){
  barfoo = null;
}
```

Comment: Why did I not think of that O.o Sometimes I just don't even think. Thanks.

Comment: ?? Was this meant to be a comment on another answer?

Comment: Sorry. Single call seems nicer.

Answer (score 2):

You can just do a single if statement with `&&` - which does short circuit evaluation.

```
if (d
    && d.hasOwnProperty('bar')
    && d.bar.hasOwnProperty('foobar')
    && d.bar.foobar.hasOwnProperty('barfoo')
) {
    // fancy things happen
}
```

The reason you use `d.hasOwnProperty('bar')` instead of just `d.bar` is in case something has polluted the object prototype.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to know is whether or not it exists, you could just do it with a try/catch

> try{
>
> ```
>   if (Foo.bar.foobar.barfoo) {
>
>       //do stuff with your thingy because you know it exists
>
>   }
> ```
>
> } catch(x) {
>
> ```
>      //you know it's no good/doesn't exist
> ```
>
> }

Comment: Works, but could affect performance, especially if used multiple times.